# string parameter in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice

My question is whether is it possible to declare string parameters in LTSpice? My specific problem is that I would like to use PWL files for the simulation, and it would be very useful if I could give the file name as a parameter. (reason: there are several other parameters belonging to a PWL file, and these parameters could be handled together).

Comment: Do a search in the LTspice help. Use "PWL file" in the search. Then look for the "wavefile=" option there. It allows a filename to be given.

Comment: Note that the `.wavefile` is limited to +/-1V, but you can also use `PWL file='c:\path\to\filename.optionalExtension'` just fine. The format is simply time/amplitude pairs separated by space, or comma (possibly other chars, as well, didn't bother trying, really).